# Can spending stability lead to a Mythos shock?

Tags: trail-of-cthulhu

Bob faces a Mythos entity and has to make a Stability test or lose 7 Stability. It's been a long day and Bob is already at -2 Stability. Bob's player chooses to spend 4 Stability points in order to (probably) automatically succeed on the test, bringing him to -6. This means that despite the success, Bob's mind is **blasted**.

But was this a mythos shock?

Here's basically all the rules say on mythos shocks, and why it matters:

> Each time you are **blasted** by a Mythos encounter or attack (when your Stability drops to between -6 and -11), your Sanity *rating* drops by 2 points.

Answer (score 1):

Reading on from the quote (page 74 of the rulebook), it says a character would only suffer one Sanity hit in this fashion per investigation. So my answer would depend on whether the event that brought Bob under 0 Stability had been a Mythos shock that caused Sanity loss. If yes, given that he passed this Stability test, I'd be inclined to not make him lose more (but willing to entertain an argument that he should lose 1). If the original Stability loss was not a Mythos shock, I would dock him the 2 points.